# UWP AdaptiveTrigger Not Triggering

Tags: xaml, uwp

I have the VisualStateManager inside the root grid, but it's not triggering the `AdaptiveTrigger`. I'm trying to change the `textblock` inside the `StackPanel`. Also, what are the rules on priority of `VisualState` setters over the default? For example, the `textblock` `CreateNewAccount` is using `x:Uid` to get a string resource, but when the `setter` tries to change the `Text` value, which one gets priority? Same with `FontSize` being set by a static resource style.

```
<Page.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="../Style/ApparentTheme.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Page.Resources>

<Grid x:Name="MainGrid" Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" Margin="20 0 20 0">
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup>
            <VisualState x:Name="Mobile_720">
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="720" />
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>

                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="CreateNewAccount.FontSize" Value="12"/>
                    <Setter Target="CreateNewAccount.Text" Value="Test"/>
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <StackPanel x:Name="FormStackPanel" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Vertical">
        <TextBlock x:Name="CreateNewAccount" x:Uid="CreateNewAccount" Style="{StaticResource TitleTextBlockStyle1366}"/>
        <TextBox x:Uid="EmailField" x:Name="emailField" 
                 Style="{StaticResource TextBoxStyle1366}" InputScope="EmailNameOrAddress"
                 Text="{Binding NewSignUp.Email, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        <TextBox x:Uid="FirstNameField" x:Name="firstNameField" 
                 Style="{StaticResource TextBoxStyle1366}" InputScope="AlphanumericFullWidth"
                 Text="{Binding NewSignUp.FirstName, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        <TextBox x:Uid="LastNameField" x:Name="lastNameField" 
                 Style="{StaticResource TextBoxStyle1366}" InputScope="AlphanumericFullWidth"
                 Text="{Binding NewSignUp.LastName, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        <PasswordBox x:Uid="PasswordField" x:Name="passwordField" 
                     Style="{StaticResource PasswordBoxStyle1366}"
                     Password="{Binding NewSignUp.Password, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        <PasswordBox x:Uid="PasswordConfirmField" x:Name="passwordConfirmField" 
                     Style="{StaticResource PasswordBoxStyle1366}"
                     Password="{Binding NewSignUp.PasswordConfirm, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        <Button x:Uid="CreateAccountButton" 
                Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle1366}"
                Command="{Binding CreateAccountCommand}" Click="CreateAccountButton_Click"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="errorMessage"
                   FontSize="16pt" Foreground="Red" Margin="0 5 0 0"
                   Text="{Binding SignUpErrorMessage, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        <ProgressRing x:Name="signUpProgressRing"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Center" IsActive="False" Height="30" Width="30"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Comment: I've tried your sample, and *AdaptiveTrigger* seems to trigger - first I see text from resources, then after window resizing I see the value from the trigger. How it look on your side?

Comment: @Romasz Hey. Yes, it does trigger. I realized the issue. I was testing on a mobile emulator and even though it was 720p, it was not quite there. I tested on desktop and when I resized the width it worked. I also realized the MinWindowWidth property suggests that it is better to design for a small form factor first, and then use AdaptiveTrigger setters to make changes for larger widths and heights. I was doing the opposite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is better to design for a small form factor, and use `AdaptiveTrigger` for larger widths and heights. Because I was doing the opposite, and testing on a smaller mobile screen, I was unable to see the changes. Here is the revised XAML:

```
<Page
x:Class="apparent_uwp.View.SignUpPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:apparent_uwp.View"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Page.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="../Style/ApparentTheme.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Page.Resources>

<Grid x:Name="MainGrid" Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" Margin="20 0 20 0">
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup>
            <VisualState x:Name="Mobile_720">
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="720" />
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>

                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="CreateNewAccount.FontSize" Value="24"/>
                    <Setter Target="MainGrid.ColumnDefinitions[0].Width" Value="*"/>
                    <Setter Target="MainGrid.ColumnDefinitions[2].Width" Value="*"/>
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <StackPanel x:Name="FormStackPanel" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Vertical" Margin="10 0 10 0">
        <TextBlock x:Name="CreateNewAccount" x:Uid="CreateNewAccount" Style="{StaticResource TitleTextBlockStyle}"/>
        <TextBox x:Uid="EmailField" x:Name="emailField" 
                 Style="{StaticResource TextBoxStyle}" InputScope="EmailNameOrAddress"
                 Text="{Binding NewSignUp.Email, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        <TextBox x:Uid="FirstNameField" x:Name="firstNameField" 
                 Style="{StaticResource TextBoxStyle}" InputScope="AlphanumericFullWidth"
                 Text="{Binding NewSignUp.FirstName, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        <TextBox x:Uid="LastNameField" x:Name="lastNameField" 
                 Style="{StaticResource TextBoxStyle}" InputScope="AlphanumericFullWidth"
                 Text="{Binding NewSignUp.LastName, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        <PasswordBox x:Uid="PasswordField" x:Name="passwordField" 
                     Style="{StaticResource PasswordBoxStyle}"
                     Password="{Binding NewSignUp.Password, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        <PasswordBox x:Uid="PasswordConfirmField" x:Name="passwordConfirmField" 
                     Style="{StaticResource PasswordBoxStyle}"
                     Password="{Binding NewSignUp.PasswordConfirm, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        <Button x:Uid="CreateAccountButton" 
                Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}"
                Command="{Binding CreateAccountCommand}" Click="CreateAccountButton_Click"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="errorMessage"
                   FontSize="16pt" Foreground="Red" Margin="0 5 0 0"
                   Text="{Binding SignUpErrorMessage, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        <ProgressRing x:Name="signUpProgressRing"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Center" IsActive="False" Height="30" Width="30"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Comment: It seems it can works when the windows size is changed. So what is your problem?